# Alt attribute value showing on Google search

Tags: html, search

I was doing a Google search on the company that I work for, and for some reason that I can't explain, the alt attribute value is showing on Google as the name of the page, as seen on the following print:

[image]

As you can see, "Ícone do Whatsapp" is the alt attribute of a floating Whatsapp icon that we have in the page, as seen here:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/5519983642028?text=Vi%20o%20site%20da%20Fast%20Tire%20e%20quero%20aproveitar%20as%20ofertas%20de%20pneus%20novos!" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="https://fasttire.com.br/themes/fasttire/assets/less/icon-whats.png" alt="Ícone do Whatsapp" style="margin-bottom:100%; height:80%; width:80%" >
</a>
```

I have no idea what could be happening here.

Comment: `alt` is an _attribute_, not a tag.

Comment: The image has the alt attribute, not the anchor

Comment: Were you doing image search or standard search?

Comment: This *looks* like either your `<title>` tag is missing/incorrectly formatted, or you may be missing meta data in your `<header>`. I would first try troubleshooting things via [this Google support doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9079920?hl=en)

Comment: Right, this whatsapp icon is on the theme of our website, meaning all pages share this in common, so for some reason this theme don't actually have a dynamic title (that to me is the right decision on this situation), so i've just added one right now, let's see what happens... Thank you for pointing out pertinent things to my question @EssXTee

Comment: But even if this solves the problem, i'm still wondering what could be happening that that particular attribute is shown, since the theme has previous images, all with alt attributes..

Answer (score 1):

Just inspected your html and it looks like Google wants to display some text there, and you don't have any other text.  Inside the **header** tag, you only have an image.

Also your **title** tag is very non-descriptive **home**

Possible solutions

1. Put a decent description of the website in the **title** tag.
2. Put a **title** attribute on the **anchor**.
3. Put a **title** attribute on the **image**.